# Javafx - Fill tableview with arraylist without adding new columns

Tags: arraylist, javafx, tableview

I'm currently trying to fill a tableview in a javafx gui with a arraylist and it's more or less working.

Here is my code:

**GUI.xml:**

```
<TableView fx:id="tableBookList">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnTitle" text="Title" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnQuantity" text="Quantity" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnUUID" text="UUID" />
        </columns>
</TableView>
```

**GUIController.java:**

```
public void setTableContent(ArrayList<Book> bookList)
{
    columnTitle = new TableColumn<>("columnTitle");
    columnQuantity = new TableColumn<>("columnQuantity");
    columnUUID = new TableColumn<>("columnUUID");

    ObservableList<Book> data = FXCollections.<Book>observableArrayList(new Book("Test", 1));

    data.addAll(bookList);

    columnTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
    columnQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, Integer>("quantity"));
    columnUUID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("uuid"));

    tableBookList.setItems(data);

    // This is working but adding three new columns every time :(
    tableBookList.getColumns().addAll(columnTitle, columnQuantity, columnUUID);

    tableBookList.refresh();
}
```

As you can read in the comment, the current setup is working but adding three new columns every time this function is called.

I searched but couldn't find a answer which I could work with.

I hope someone could show me where my problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many times do you call the function setTableContent in our program?

Comment: Why are you creating new table columns at all, if they are defined in the FXML file?

Comment: At the moment this function is called manually, but I want to be called after every change of the arraylist so that the displayed list will be updated. So this function should replace the data in the tableview with the given list.

Comment: Ah I got it, when I remove the new initialization of the columns its working!
Should I answer my own question by myself or is there a better way to do this? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You should remove the three lines with `new TableColumn<>(...)` entirely, and also the `tableBookList.getColumns().addAll(...)`. You should also move the three lines with `setCellValueFactory(...)` to the `initialize()` method: you only need to do that once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `cellValueFactory`s in the `initialize` method of the controller or in the fxml and do not recreate the columns. Furthermore calling `refresh` is unnecessary:

```
public void setTableContent(ArrayList<Book> bookList) {
    ObservableList<Book> data = FXCollections.<Book>observableArrayList(new Book("Test", 1));
    data.addAll(bookList);

    tableBookList.setItems(data);
}
```

#### Version 1: Using fxml

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableBookList">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnTitle" text="Title">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="title"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnQuantity" text="Quantity">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="quantity"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnUUID" text="UUID">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="uuid"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

#### Version 2: using the `initialize` method

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    columnTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
    columnQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, Integer>("quantity"));
    columnUUID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("uuid"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The FXML file already creates the three table columns, and adds them to the table view's columns list. You should not do that again in the controller.

Additionally, you only need to set the cell value factories on the table columns once, not every time you call `setTableContent`. So your controller should look like

```
public void initialize() {
    columnTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
    columnQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, Integer>("quantity"));
    columnUUID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("uuid"));
}

public void setTableContent(ArrayList<Book> bookList)
{
    ObservableList<Book> data = FXCollections.<Book>observableArrayList(new Book("Test", 1));

    data.addAll(bookList);


    tableBookList.setItems(data);

}
```

Alternatively, since you don't retain a separate reference to the `ObservableList` you create, you can reduce `setTableContent` to:

```
public void setTableContent(ArrayList<Book> bookList)
{
    tableBookList.getItems().setAll(bookList);   
}
```

(Note the call to `refresh()` is also redundant: the table knows when its items have changed.)